# How to Auto Increment Attribute Based on Nearest Point?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop

An authority I am working with would like their Hydrants, a point shapefile, to be renumbered based on their location. I am looking for any python script that would help me A. Find the next closest Hydrant B. Generate a number C. Increment that number for all hydrants.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop version 10.0.

Comment: In general what you seem to be asking for is not possible: it will not usually be the case that the nearest neighbors of each hydrant can have numbers close to one another.  (When that's possible, the hydrants basically have to be in a line and numbered sequentially from one end to the other--that's great for a one-street town, but becomes problematic in larger jurisdictions!)  Do you have additional criteria in mind for making the necessary compromises in finding a numbering that works for *most* hydrants?

Comment: Thanks for your time and information. I will continue to look for a work around.

Comment: It could be possible by starting from an arbitrary point and then choosing the closest hydrant using the Near (Analysis), then exclude the first one and look for the second one, and so on. You could define some zones if you want the hydrants numbered in one area first.